# Usar UpdateView para dos operaciones Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-urls

Quiero usar una vista para hacer dos operaciones. De una lista de artículos quiero agregar o restar la cantidad actual del artículo.

Dupliqué mi vista y cambié el nombre para reflejar la operación que quiero hacer, creé 2 URLs con nombres distintos para cada uno ligado al view que quiero ejectutar. A pesar de esto sigo teniendo el mismo campo al momento de hacer la operación (solo muestra el campo para restar la cantidad).

```
class Items(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    codigo_proveedor = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey('Categorias', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    c_minima = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    c_actual = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    c_descuento = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
    c_incremento = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
    proveedor = models.ForeignKey('Proveedores', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    carrito = models.ForeignKey('Carrito', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True )
    p_unitario = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True )
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    material = models.ForeignKey(Materiales, null=True, blank=True)
    tipo = models.ForeignKey(Tipo, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.c_actual = self.c_actual - self.c_descuento
        self.c_actual =self.c_actual + self.c_incremento 
        self.total = self.c_actual * self.p_unitario
        super(Items, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


    def __str__(self):
       return '%s %s %s %s' % (self.nombre, str(self.categoria), str(self.c_actual), str(self.total))
```

views.py

```
# DESCUENTA ARTICULOS DE LA LISTA DE ELEMENTOS 
class CatItemUpdateDesc(UpdateView):
    model = Items
    fields = ['c_descuento']
    template_name_suffix= '_update_form'
    context_object_name = 'items'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('inventory:cat-list')


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CatItemUpdateDesc, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categoria'] = Items.objects.all()
        return context

# INCREMENTA ARTICULOS EN LA LISTA 
class CatItemUpdateInc(UpdateView):
    model = Items
    fields = [ 'c_incremento']
    template_name_suffix= '_update_form'
    context_object_name = 'items'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('inventory:cat-list')


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CatItemUpdateInc, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categoria'] = Items.objects.all()
        return context
```

urls.py

```
#HACE EL DESCUENTO DE LAS CANTIDADES EXISTENTES
url(r'^item_update/(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', views.CatItemUpdateDesc.as_view(), name='CatItemUpdateDesc'),

#HACE EL DESCUENTO DE LAS CANTIDADES EXISTENTES
url(r'^item_update/(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', views.CatItemUpdateInc.as_view(), name='CatItemUpdateInc'),
```

¿Alguna sugerencia sobre cómo puedo lograr lo que quiero?

Comment: yo realize hace unos meses un sistema de inventarios y ventas , el cual empleaba ajax para no complicarme tanto.. te sugiero esta opcion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás usando la misma expresión regular en ambas URLs:

```
r'^item_update/(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$'
```

A mí me parece que puedes manejar los dos casos en una sola vista usando algún tipo de argumento que te ayude a decidir si incrementas o decrementas. Si estás empeñado en usar dos vistas distintas (y por lo tanto, dos URLs distintas) entonces agrégale algo para diferenciarlas:

```
#HACE EL DESCUENTO DE LAS CANTIDADES EXISTENTES
url(r'^item_update/(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/desc/$', views.CatItemUpdateDesc.as_view(), name='CatItemUpdateDesc'),

#HACE EL DESCUENTO DE LAS CANTIDADES EXISTENTES
url(r'^item_update/(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/inc/$', views.CatItemUpdateInc.as_view(), name='CatItemUpdateInc'),
```

Si observas, le he agregado un `desc/` y un `inc/` respectivamente.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia,  me agarda la idea de una sola vista para los dos casos. Intentare aplicarla ... saludos